# Problem with a simple jQuery Templates example

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-templates

I am using `jquery-tmpl` and receiving the following `JSON` data, which I am using for form validation in ASP.NET MVC3:

```
{"Status":1,"Message":"Oh dear, what have you done. Check the list of errors dude!","Errors":["The Contents field is required.","The Date Created field is required.","The Date Updated field is required.","The Updated By field is required."]}
```

My template looks like this:

```
<script id="ResponseTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
{{each(i, error) Errors}}
    <li>${error}</li>
{{/each}}
</script>
```

My `JSON` POST is as follows:

```
var data = {
    Contents: "This is a test",
    DateCreated: "",
    DateUpdated: "",
    UpdatedBy: "Ben"
};

$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("save", "note")',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (result) {
        alert(result.Errors);
        $("#Responses").tmpl(result).appendTo("#ResponseTemplate")
    }
});
```

The data is correct. The alert is showing the Errors array as a string. The template just is not working.

The answer must be simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just have `Responses` and `ResponseTemplate` mixed up:

```
$("#ResponseTemplate").tmpl(result).appendTo("#Responses");
```

Here's your example (without the AJAX calls): http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/GcqZX/

You could also write your template like this:

```
<script id="ResponseTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <li>${$data}</li>
</script>
```

And call it like this:

```
$("#ResponseTemplate").tmpl(result.Errors).appendTo("#Responses");
```

(Not sure if it's actually any better, but just wanted to point out that you don't have to use `{{each}}` in this case).

Comment: Ta Andrew. I figured this out as well last night. Was too tired when I put this together originally! JSFiddle = Awesome.

Comment: @Junto: Good to hear you figured it out.  Yeah JSFiddle is a great tool!